# Is is possible to add a print in windows 10 on a different network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer, network-printer

My main goal is to add a printer to my Windows 10 computer, however the setup I have here is a bit strange.

My ISP moldem allows my to connect multiple network cables to it. One cable is directed connected to my Windows 10 PC. Another cable is connect to a router that handles my wireless connections.

My printer is connected to my wireless network, so all my wireless devices have access to it, however, since my PC is directly connected to my ISP moldem and is not on my wireless network, it can not automatically find my print and I can not access my router through my PC, because I believe they are in different networks.

Is there a way around this? My router is in the attic and I can not connect it to my PC and the only network my printer accepts is wireless.

Answer (score 2):

Set your WiFi router to be an Access Point only.
This will hand DHCP server duties to the main router.

Reboot all devices from the router 'inwards'.

All your devices should now be on the same subnet & be able to communicate.

Comment: "Reboot all devices from the router 'inwards'. " What does this mean exactly? I just turn off and on again?

Comment: Yes, shut it all down, power off. Then power back up from nearest the 'outside world' inwards until you get to computers & phones etc last

Answer (score -1):

Several options exist.

1. Buy a cheap USB wifi dongle and connect your PC to the wifi.  You could make adjustments to the windows firewall to block the wifi connection from doing anything else.
2. Get a raspberry Pi 4
   Setup hostapd to make a wifi host spot
   attach the network connector of the Pi 4 to your wired network.
   Setup samba for file and print sharing and share your printer over the network that way.
   In addition, you could attach your other device to the Pi 4 depending on there distance.
3. Adjust your routers security setting.
   Problem here is that some routers don't have the necessary settings.
4. Buy a pre-built wifi network print server

Comment: How would a adjust the security settings?

Comment: Don't let this answer distract you. Your issue is you have 2 subnets created by 2 different routers. All you need to do is reduce that to one subnet.

Comment: @user3347814  In the windows firewall you can block based on IP and port.  Block all other ports on the wifi subnet besides 135 through 139 (tcp and udp) and tcp 445, and the printer may need 53 for dns lookups.  Then block all IPs outbound except for the printer on that subnet.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to reduce to one subnet?

Comment: @user3347814 You would have to reconfigure either your router and or wireless access point.